# Is it possible to show only the confirm, and not the cancel button icon in Prime Faces DataTable rowEditor?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to show only the confirm, and not the cancel button icon in Prime Faces DataTable rowEditor?

[image]

Comment: show some code.

Comment: @Plochie: thank you for your reply, It's not a problem on some code already written, I ask for the code because on how to do it because it's not documented anywhere, this is the showcase for editing datatable primefaces: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

Comment: If it (are never before requested feature) is not documented anywhere it most likely is not possible in the component. Two solutions then... 1: Override the source for this component, 2: use some css to hide it (it is all html, css and javascript on the client). But a strange requirement anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended myself with this approach

As stated by @Kukeltje it's possible to manage similar problems on client using
some css to hide it (it is all html, css and javascript on the client).

I choose jquery to handle html, css, and javascript (I'm relatively new to jsf/primefaces but I read it's based on jquery).

So in managed bean I was able launch scripts like this:

```
PrimeFaces.current().executeScript("$('#myForm\\\\:myContainer .ui-row-editor-close').eq(-1).remove();");
```

or even in XHTML/JS script like this:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="myScripts.js" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myForm\\:myContainer .ui-row-editor-close").last().remove();
});
```

Anyway with this approach you need to be carefull, any ajax call which update part of the page involved reset to default, so cancel button will re-appear.

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS? Much simpler.

Comment: @BalusC, thx for the advice, I need to control when conditionally apply the behavior, I don't know if css is enough, anyway maybe you could post an example as answer... for now I had to close some issues and my approach solved, but for my future, or future of someoneelse, it could be useful

Comment: Hmmm... I posted the same as BalusC but it disappeared... And btw, I never mentioned jquery (like you state I did) but I did mention css

Comment: @Kukeltje, I'm sorry I misunderstood.. :) ...corrected the answer ...any different approach for the future will be appreciated... thx again.